# Convert GUID to varchar(32)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, guid, varchar

How can I convert a GUID which is `36` characters to a VARCHAR(32)?

I'm trying to copy data from one table to another. There are two similar columns from these two tables.

1. **Table1.colx** is a GUID so it is `36` characters in length in total due to the hyphens
2. The corresponding column is **table2.colx** but it is a VARCHAR(32)

I am looking for a way to convert a GUID to VARCHAR, but I've got to remove the hyphens.  So far I have been unsuccessful in my attempts to find a way to do this.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I assume this is SQL Server, from the SSMS tag.

Convert the GUID to a string, then replace the hyphens with empty strings:

```
REPLACE(CAST(table1.colx AS VARCHAR(36)),'-','')
```

Comment: Ahhhh, that makes a world of sense.  Thank you very much.  I was thinking too close-minded trying to do it all in one step.

Comment: Could you perhaps assist me with an example of converting it to string first?  I'm wondering if I should set up a temporary table or something...

Comment: It's in the answer: `CAST(table1.colx AS VARCHAR(36))`. This will return the string representation of the GUID. You can use this anywhere you would normally reference the column (in a SELECT, WHERE, JOIN, etc). If you're having trouble figuring out where to put this, open a new question and include your code. Ping me here and I'll be happy to answer it.

Comment: I got it, that's all you needed to say.  Thank you!