# Binary GUID to string with less characters SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, text, binary, guid, varchar

Following the procedure here: 
[Convert GUID to varchar(32)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222343/convert-guid-to-varchar32/16222390#16222390?newreg=218fab3ec3224bf5a2d814e55fbcd834)

with this line of code:

```
REPLACE(CAST([ResultsSetID] AS VARCHAR), '0x', '') AS TrimmedID
```

I cannot get result in standard letters and numbers with above code.

The aim is to return the GUID without the `0x` prefix

Instead output is in other symbols, which is undesired - help appreciated

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbgYh.png)

Comment: You didn't use the code that you found at that link. You have a varchar here with no length. As such it will use the default length of 30 which is too short. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length

Comment: Apart from what @SeanLange mentioned, you want to use `CONVERT` and specify an additional parameter. e.g. `CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), ResultsSetID, 1)`. Please note this section of the page on cast/convert: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql#binary-styles

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help @SeanLange and  @ZLK I was able to get this to work now with the following code:

```
(REPLACE(convert(varchar(max),[ResultsSetID],1),'0x','' ) ) as TrimmedID
```

[image]

Comment: Side note, it's generally good practice to avoid `varchar(max)`.  You could just use `varchar(34)` here.  http://rusanu.com/2010/03/22/performance-comparison-of-varcharmax-vs-varcharn/

Comment: Thanks for the tip @AaronDietz I will bear this in mind!